# any way to make script work while ctrl key is pressed down

Tags: autohotkey

```
#SingleInstance ignore
~LButton::
    Time := A_TickCount
    KeyWait, LButton
    If ((A_TickCount-Time) < 300)
        Click
Return
```

i am trying to make autohotkey when enabled [via eventghost] let me select multiple points in onenote by selecting the word in just one mouse click on each rather than 2 , but i couldn't make it work with ctrl key pressed down to select multiple points at a time. the above code also i found online to make a single click registered as double click.

Comment: What do you mean by 'select multiple points'? Click on multiple words in the same sentence? (not allowable). Shade full sentences using the cross icon that appears? (doesn't need double-click to do this).  Something else? Does OneNote allow you to do what you're trying to do if you do it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
^LButton::
  click
  click
  return
```